# How do I select an element within a table using Python Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, element, sendkeys

I am trying to use Python Selenium to input a custom value in an input box on a website.

The html shows this element is stored within a table. The html and my code are shown below. I have tried sending keys on the element with class 'filterLink' and the class 'value'. Is it possible to send keys on a table data element? 
Or should I be looking somewhere else in the html to send keys on this field?

The error I am getting is "Message: unknown error: cannot focus element"

Thanks very much!!

```
<div class="ContentSourceTypeData show" group="Provider Type">
    <ul>
       <li>
         <table class="listItem">
           <tbody>
             <tr>
                <td class="label">
                   <a class="filterLink" href="javascript:void(0);" value="bank" name="Banks" address="true">
                      <span class="value">Banks</span>&nbsp;(1831)
                   </a>
                </td> 
              </tr>
          .....

My code...

index_details_elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('ContentSourceTypeData')

nameTable = index_details_elem.find_elements_by_class_name("listItem")[0] # 
Select first listItem as element
nameDataElem = nameTable.find_element_by_class_name("label")

#nameInputElem = nameDataElem.find_elements_by_class_name("value")  #used the above line instead of this one as the 'span' element seemed to be causing an issue
#print nameElem.location() 
#nameDataElem.click() # removed as I can't click in a table

nameDataElem.send_keys("lookup value")
```

Comment: there is no "input" tag in the DOM.. How can you send sendkeys?

Comment: Can you provide more information like the website that you're trying to automate? Because I can't see an input tag in the HTML code

Comment: Sorry I didn't add the website. It's just one that requires a license for the data and a paid for username/password so I can't share that. 
What is the 'DOM'?
I haven't seen an input flag on other webelements that I have been able to use sendkeys on

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that you are able to send_keys to any selenium webelement. I would probably use a css selector (Maybe there is another element on the page with a name of "label"). Try doing:

```
webelement = "a[class=\"filterLink\"]"
webelement.send_keys("lookup value")
```

That will select all "a" elements, with a class value of "filterLink", and then send the keys "lookup value" to it.

Comment: Thanks, I've checked that. All the 'filterlink' classes are of the same structure, and none have an input section. Maybe it's because this is a dropdown on the website rather than a free type box

Comment: That could be. Is the dropdown showing when you do send_keys?